# Webpack config issue with loaders when running gulp serve or build

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack, gulp, webpack-2

Am new to using webpack and used Fountain Web App to scaffold my setup and then adding in my own stuff. Am running into issues I am not sure what else to do with. I have searched and tried, but not sure if the issues are being caused by loaders or what.

When I run gulp serve or build, I get this:

```
C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard>gulp serve
[14:23:43] Loading C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\browsersync.js
[14:23:43] Loading C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\karma.js
[14:23:44] Loading C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\misc.js
[14:23:44] Loading C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\webpack.js
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
[14:23:45] Using gulpfile C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulpfile.js
[14:23:45] Starting 'serve'...
[14:23:45] Starting 'webpack:watch'...
[14:23:45] 'webpack:watch' errored after 121 ms
[14:23:45] WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.
   Loaders should be updated to allow passing this option via loader options in module.rules.
   Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to switch loaders into debug mode:
   plugins: [
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
       debug: true
     })
   ]
    at webpack (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
    at webpackWrapper (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\webpack.js:24:26)
    at gulp.task.done (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\gulp_tasks\webpack.js:15:3)
    at taskWrapper (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at taskWrapper (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at taskWrapper (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:293:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\vapor\source\mgmtPortal\dashboard\node_modules\async-done\index.js:36:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
[14:23:45] 'serve' errored after 127 ms
```

My webpack config looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

// const rules = {
//     // ...
//     componentStyles: {
//         test: /\.scss$/,
//         loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
//         exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app')
//     },
//     fonts: {
//         test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
//         loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
//     },
//     // ...
// }

// const config = module.exports = {};

// config.module = {
//     rules: [
//         // ...
//         rules.componentStyles,
//         rules.fonts,
//         // ...
//     ]
// };

module.exports = {
    module: {
        // preLoaders: [{
        //     test: /\.js$/,
        //     exclude: /node_modules/,
        //     loader: 'eslint'
        // }],

        loaders: [{
                test: /.json$/,
                loaders: [
                    'json'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style',
                    'css',
                    'sass',
                    'postcss'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                loaders: [
                    'html'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "Tether": "tether"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: conf.path.src('index.html')
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ // inject ES5 modules as global vars
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Tether: 'tether'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            conf.paths.src
        )
    ],
    postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    entry: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
};
```

Can any of you lend a hand with helping me on this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this specific error you need to remove `debug: true,` from your webpack config. The error is saying that the `debug` parameter is not valid for Webpack 2, and it was only valid in webpack 1.

The line of the error is here:

```
[14:23:45] WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.
```

It sounds like you upgraded to webpack 2, maybe unintentionally. If it was on purpose, you can view [the migration guide here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/), on how to properly structure your configuration file. It likely needs more changed if you plan on staying with Webpack 2.

If it was unintentional, you can reinstall webpack by running the npm command, but it is not recommended and not supported anymore.

```
npm install --save webpack@1.15.0
```

Comment: Thanks for that Adam! Yes - I did load up webpack 2, but didn't think it would do this. Need to rethink the progression to 2....

Comment: The migration process isn't too bad, just be sure to read the error messages and try to follow the migration guide. It's a little tricky to jump into without prior Webpack knowledge, but I'm sure you'll do fine!